# Getting user info from Azure API App when authenticated via browser form

Tags: c#, authentication, azure, azure-api-apps

When authenticating in Chrome and `x-zumo-auth` header using Postman, my API app successfully identifies a user's upn using the following code in the controller:

```cs
Runtime runtime = Runtime.FromAppSettings(Request);
EmaUserInfo user = runtime.CurrentUser;
TokenResult token = await user.GetRawTokenAsync("aad");
string upn = token.Claims[ClaimTypes.Upn];
```

However, when using the code from Microsoft's [AzureCards](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/API-Apps-DotNet-AzureCards-Sample/blob/master/AzureCards.ConsoleClient/Program.cs) Console Client example (adding a browser to a forms window and capture the zumo token), I am unable to get the user's aad token and get the following error from the API app:

```
Request to https://[gateway].azurewebsites.net/api/tokens?tokenName=aad&api-version=2015-01-14 GET failed BadRequest 400 (Bad Request)
{
  "status": 400,
  "source": "https://[gateway].azurewebsites.net/api/tokens?tokenName=aad&api-version=2015-01-14",
  "message": "Microservice '[API App]' only has permissions for token ''. Can't get token 'aad'"
}
```

Interestingly, this even happens when I'm set a breakpoint and copy the zumo token from my test program into postman. The program fails and postman returns successfully. As far as I can tell, they're sending the exact same requests. What could I be missing?

*Edit:* I've done some more testing and discovered that the Postman method yields the same error when done in incognito mode. This leads me to believe that it's not just the `x-zumo-auth` header that needs to be set, but that there's also some cookie that needs to be set in order for the user work properly. I can also get the error if I generate the token, delete the cookies from the apiapp url and POST a request with only the token.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The API App should have an: authentication" array with which looks like this:

```
"authentication": [{"type": "aad"}]
```

Your final apiapp.json should be something like that:

```
{
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schemas/2014-11-01/apiapp.json#",
"id": "YourApiApps",
"namespace": "microsoft.com",
"gateway": "2015-01-14",
"version": "1.0.0",
"title": "YourApiApps",
"summary": "",
"author": "",
"endpoints": {
    "apiDefinition": "/swagger/docs/v1",
    "status": null
},
"authentication": [{"type": "aad"}]}
```

Then, please redeploy and check again. It should fix the issue.

Comment: This didn't work either, but I've updated my question with more information. It seems that for access, all I need is the `x-zumo-auth` header, but if I want to do anything with the user, I need to have some cookies.

Comment: The cookie is named x-zumo-auth as well. If you open Fiddler2 or the Dev Tools on Chrome and go to Resources -> Cookies, you'll see it there along with the Affinity cookie. What happens is that when the header is there, you get redirected and returned with the Cookie. Then you have to include the cookie on each request. In fiddler it looks like:

Cookie: x-zumo-auth=eyuakdfkasdkfk235asdf...

Comment: I was having the same issue for microsoftaccount, and adding that line to the apiapp.json file did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any delay to this taking effect? I've added this to my apiapp.json and it shows up properly in the remote directory, but I'm still getting "microservice only has permissions for token ''."

Comment: You have to restart the gateway.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like I had to restart both the gateway and the api app within the portal a few times before the changes took effect, but this is definitely fixed the problem.